# What word best describes someone who doesn't put up with other people's crap?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes someone who doesn't put up with other people's crap.

Comment: would an idiom be accepted?

Comment: A common way to express this (not a single word) is "does not suffer fools lightly" (or "gladly").

Answer (score 1):

Assertiveness is a skill regularly referred to in social and communication skills training. Being assertive means being able to stand up for your own or other people's rights in a calm and positive way, without being either aggressive, or passively accepting 'wrong'.

Comment: This thoughtful answer only needs a source or two with a definition for your word choice and some examples of its usage in sentences, to be more persuasive.

Answer (score 0):

***taciturn.***

Definiton: taciturn
tac·i·turn

tac·i·turn [tássi tùrn]
adj 
 silent by nature: habitually uncommunicative or reserved in speech and manner
[Late 18th century. Via French taciturne < Latin taciturnus < tacitus (see tacit)]
-tac·i·tur·ni·ty [tàssi túrnətee], , n 
-tac·i·turn·ly [tássi tùrnlee], , adv 
Word Key: Synonyms
See silent...as in pointedly silent.

Comment: Your answer would be more persuasive with definitions, sources, and example sentences provided.

Comment: The nature of the Question did not suggest an intention at formal expression. But I'll post a definition to encourage confidence in trying my improved answer.